# "//EX[2,1,["java.lang.IllegalArgumentException/1755012560","Invalid session"],0,7]" text is displayed in Response data

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I recorded the log in and log out of the application in Jmeter and while Run is clicked, the following message

> "//EX[2,1,["java.lang.IllegalArgumentException/1755012560","Invalid session"],0,7]"

is displayed in the Response data blog while log out or closing the application HTTP request is compiled. Is there any way to compile with out getting this message.

Comment: share screenshot with more details of your script.

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that you're missing [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) which handles cookie-based authentication and maintains session information.

If adding HTTP Cookie Manager to your test plan doesn't help - record the sametest several times and mention any changes in recorded requests. If they are - you need to perform correlation - the process of extracting dynamic mandatory parameters from previous response and adding them to next request. Basing on your response nature the choices can be in:

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

Answer (score 1):

According to your response, it seems you are testing a GWT RPC application:

- http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html

Load Testing and scripting GWTRPC is not easy and almost impossible with Core JMeter only as:
 - Decoding GWTRPC response is difficult whenever you need to extract some info from response.
 - Making part of the request Variable is very difficult

If you do not variabilize, as with any other protocol, your load test will not be realistic.

You need for this a plugin:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-gwt-rpc-applications-with-ubik-load-pack-plugin-for-jmeter/

Disclaimer : My company distributes this solution.